# Is there a movie or series with almost the same plot as "Archive 81"?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, horror

I am currently watching [Archive 81](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_81) show on Netflix. As I am nearing the end of first series I experienced strong feeling of déjà-vu, to the point I became convinced I watched something very similar before.

Story points that rings the bell most loudly:

- Tapes (or video files) recovered from the place of a disaster.
- Main character got to watch the tapes and feels connected to a person appearing on the tapes and ends up believing the person from videos is not really dead
- Convoluted cult plot and 'ghost' activity

> - Somehow underwhelming ending of "Aliens did it" sort

Has anyone an idea about whether something else like this series exists?

Comment: Just to get the obvious out of the way, have you ever listened to the podcast the show is based on?

Comment: No, I did not. And I had very visual  kind of deja vu. It was like "hmm I have already seen it" rather then "hmm I know the story".

Comment: There was also something similar to Thrill seekers in Doctor who first episode, The Orville had a character looking at tapes of someone who long died and feel a connection. May be Fringe had similar stories.